# C#: does SortedList<TKey,TValue> implement IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, sortedlist

According to the documentation of [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)
and [SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)
they both  implement 
`IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` and `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey,TValue>`. The doc versions for .net 4.5.2 say the same, so my project, targeting C# 6.0 (which is .NET 4.6, wikipedia says), should be covered by that.

According to the compiler from VS 2015, they don't.
I cannot pass a `SortedDictionary<int, string>` to this function:

```
private static void funcIROCollKvp1 (IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>> i_rocollkvp)
```

Which one is wrong?

Here's the full code:

```
private static void funcIROCollKvp1 (IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>> i_rocollkvp)
{
}

private static void Main ()
{
  SortedList<int, string> listkvp = new SortedList<int, string> ();
  SortedDictionary<int, string> dict = new SortedDictionary<int, string> ();

  funcIROCollKvp1 (listkvp);
  funcIROCollKvp1 (dict);
}
```

1>D:\Visual Studio Projects\testTKS_vs2015\test03\Program.cs(18,24,18,31): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection>'
1>D:\Visual Studio Projects\testTKS_vs2015\test03\Program.cs(19,24,19,28): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection>'

Comment: I wrote the same code with .NET 4.5 Compiler and it worked fine without any error. Could you share the exact error message you are getting and the relevant code of  `funcIROCollKvp1 ` method and how you are generating `SortedDictionary<int, string>` and

Comment: `my project, targeting C# 6.0 (which is .NET 4.6, wikipedia says)` - Please can you share a screenshot of your project settings demonstrating this - in your project settings you should be setting the exact version of .NET you are targeting, so the C# version shouldn't really enter into it...

Comment: @RB: I tested with language version "default" and "C# 6.0" in the project properties.

Comment: @TobiasKnauss Yes, but what is your `Target Framework` - that's the key thing that decides what .NET version you are targeting...

Comment: @RB: 4.5.2. Didn't find it in the first place. I already wondered if this setting got lost.

Comment: The .Net framework version is independent from the c# version.

Comment: I see the same error if I choose 4.5 or 4.5.x.  It goes away if I choose 4.6.  Looks like you have to cast to IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>> manually if you target those versions.  I'm using VS2017.

Comment: @Kyle Huff: okay, that makes sense. Seems to be missing Compiler logic in .net 4.5.x, same reason why C++/CLI never knew that array implements IList<>. I just didn't expect that in the "well-maintained" C#... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't say you can't pass them, it just says it doesn't know how.  You can manually cast the objects to IReadOnlyCollection.

```
        funcIROCollKvp1((IReadOnlyCollection < KeyValuePair<int, string> > )listkvp);
        funcIROCollKvp1((IReadOnlyCollection < KeyValuePair<int, string> > )dict);
```